# PayPal module in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, e-commerce, paypal

I want to download a module or extension or component for Joomla to integrate with PayPal. I have tried a lot but I haven't found any.

Can you help?

Comment: So, what do you expect? Should we google one up for you? Or should we code one for you? How much are you willing to pay for either of these services?

Answer (score 1):

The nicepaypal plugin provides a simple way to add an "add to cart / buy" button within your content through a shortcode { } .

details can be found at the trinitronic site - [documentation](http://www.trinitronic.com/index.php/Downloads/nice-paypal-button-documentation.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add a link in any page with joomla to integrate with paypal.

On line utility: http://www.codetransit.com/generators/paypal_link_generator.php

Example result:

[Add to cart!](http://www.codetransit.com/generators/paypal_link_generator.php?item=Stack+Overflow+answer&item_id=123&dollars=100&cents=00&currency_code=GBP&paypal_account=info%40evillot.com&process=Generate+Link)